# Deploy Wicket webapp in Jdeveloper IntegratedServer

Tags: deployment, weblogic, wicket, jdeveloper

I wish to run HelloWorld project with Apache Wicket, Jdeveloper 11g release 2 (Windows 7,64 bit). I am trying to deploy to the IntegratedServer but I get the following error.

```
[03:33:43 PM] Weblogic Server Exception: weblogic.application.ModuleException: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
[03:33:43 PM] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
[03:33:43 PM]   See server logs or server console for more details.
[03:33:43 PM] weblogic.application.ModuleException: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
[03:33:43 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[03:33:43 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[03:33:43 PM] Remote deployment failed (oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.common.Jsr88RemoteDeployer)
```

I added the jar for slf4j, so what is wrong here?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project properties->libraries make sure that the library that contains the missing jar is marked as "deploy by default".
Or alternatively copy the jar into the WebLogic's lib directory.
Should be something like:
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.4.39.64.36.1\DefaultDomain\lib

Comment: Copying the jar into the WebLogic's lib directory solved the problem! Thank you!